# Transmitting to and from low earth orbit?

Tags: propagation, satellites, uhf, range

I'm a hobbyist and I'm currently thinking about building a CubeSat. I'm currently designing PCBs, casing, etc. I was wondering what variables are involved with sending data to and from 250 km - 350 km orbit using a frequency of 2.4 GHz and how I should calculate how far the signal will reach.

Comment: I think ↑ that question I just linked has pretty much the complete answer you're looking for.

Comment: even we are building our own satellite and rockets too, for our satellite it would cost around 1500-2000 USD to be launched to a low earth orbit